# Nginx+Django From novice to advanced

Tags: django, nginx, webserver

I have near zero experience with web server. Currently working on a Django project in development mode. Need to know how to start and proceed with nginx and django. I prefer books over tutorials, can someone recommend some books or detailed tutorial like: WHat is a web server, how it all works, nginx in detials, separating web server from application server, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should do choice from [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) or [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface). It's protocols  uses for communicates between webserver(Nginx) and application(Django). 
Secondly, you must [install Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install), may be better from source.
Third, you must install python, pip and virtualenv(not necessarily, but for convenience) to the production server. Last, you must run Django as:

Example:

`./manage.py runfcgi method=prefork socket=/var/run/django.sock pidfile=/var/run/django.pid maxchildren=10 maxspare=10 minspare=2 maxrequest=100 daemonize=true`

It's all. Then you can set up it. You can use approaches from:

1. Django site [DjangoAndNginx](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx)
2. Nginx [DjangoFastCGI](http://wiki.nginx.org/DjangoFastCGI)
3. Nginx [PythonFlup](http://wiki.nginx.org/PythonFlup)